# Can I create my own success URL for Stripe Checkout (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, checkout

I'm building a checkout session on Stripe.

Can I create my own success url like this:

```
success_url: 'https://example.com/success?mysessionid='+session.id
```

in server-side function

```
app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
```

I've tried to use this
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page
but it didn't work.
I just want to know which purchase has been completed by payment in Stripe.

Thanks

EDIT: Also what would that mean for security if I use GET? I'm already retrieving last few payments from Stripe to check if this particular payment has truly been made - before I create an Invoice.

**EDIT 2**: **I just noticed that the nodejs example on Stripe's page is using a POST method for success page. But all other languages (PHP, Ruby, Java..) are using a GET method!!! I just sent a question to Stripe.. Will let you know what their answer is...**

Comment: After a successful transaction, you're sending your users to another page. Like redirecting. What error are you getting?

Comment: If I use GET, I get no error, if I use POST, it redirects to 404, but it throws no error.

Comment: If I use what Stripe suggests (URL posted in question), where you add 
"success_url: "http://yoursite.com/order/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
then I get this error -> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Are you using ruby or nodejs? Make sure you're hitting `success` and not `create-checkout-session`. Also see if you get `mysessionid`. This is obvisouly an issue from your router, I don't know what your set up looks like so its hard to debug.

Comment: I'm using nodejs. I'm hitting success, because if I use GET, then I get response ok, buit if I change it to POST, then I get 404. I'm waiting an answer from my server provider if Stripe's POST it getting blocked, because we're still in building mode and therefore on our test server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just 'heard' from Stripe. They said I might be on to something - that on nodejs example 'https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page' might be a mistake. They put it on their queue of issues ...
So, I'll just use a GET method for now.

```
app.GET('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
```

Thanks for all your help !

Answer (score 0):

To create a success "page" in node.js based on your success URL:

```js
app.post('/success', async function(req, res) {
  var session_id = req.query.mysessionid;
  res.send(`<html><body><h1>Thanks for your order!</h1></body></html>`);
});
```

Comment: I get a 404 with this. Like my server expects a GET not a POST. Also it returns this URL: https://example.com/success?mysessionid=60e5343243243
If I use GET ( like app.GET('/success' ... ) then it's working.

Comment: Just letting you know that I'm now waiting for my service provider to let me know if they're blocking POST requests as GET is working.

Comment: I had a typo. Try now. Hopefully it works.